# How to get the value of unchecked item (not all existing unchecked) in a group of checkboxes right away on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can get the value of un-checked checkbox right away after un-checking? I am not willing to get the all unchecked checkboxes but only the one that unchecked right now.

```js
$('input:checkbox[name=vehicle]').on("change", function() {
  var val = $('input:checkbox[name=vehicle]:checked').val();
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    console.log("The " + val + " is checked")
  } else {
    console.log("The " + val + " is un-checked")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> Bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> Car<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Boat"> Boat<br>
```

As you can see I am able to get the value of checked item on the fly but how I can get the value on on checked one?

Answer (score -1):

you could use vanilla Javascript like so:

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByName("vehicle")).forEach(item => item.addEventListener("click", e => {
  console.log(`${e.target.value} checked ${e.target.checked}`);
}));
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> Bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> Car<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Boat"> Boat<br>
```